# Loading Emulator after building android source code (froyo)

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source

I am using Ubuntu-10.04 (32-bit) with Java-5
and i had build android2.2 source code successfully (verified `system.img` & `root.img` in `out/target/product/generic` directory),
but when i starts my emulator its just loading.
i also tried to start it with following ways,

- `out/host/linux-x86/bin/emulator -sysdir out/target/product/generic/ -system out/target/product/generic/system.img -ramdisk out/target/product/generic/ramdisk.img -data out/target/product/generic/userdata.img -kernel prebuilt/android-arm/kernel/kernel-qemu -sdcard sdcard.img -skindir sdk/emulator/skins -skin WVGA800 -scale 0.7 -memory 512 -partition-size 1024`

- set_stuff_for_environment

- export USE_CCACHE=1
  ccache -M 10G

I also rebuilt with

```
lunch full-eng
$ make -j4
```

but still i am not able to see home screen, its just loading

Answer (score 0):

I having same issue..
It was solved by reinstalling OS

Comment: thnx for your reply @Alex.. but i am not supposed to do that, it may be my last option but can't uninstall it ri8 now. please if u have any other solutions..